# Why does :hover on td not work?

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I want to display two different contrasting sets of data, so I set up a table as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="dataA">HELLO</td>
        <td class="dataB">LOL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="aDescription">lol</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also included an animation on hover, such that a complementary explanation to the comparison is provided in the next table row (like the one with `#aDescription`)

```
td{
    width: 50%
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center
}

#aDescription{
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.5s
}

.dataA:hover + #aDescription{
    opacity: 1 
}
```

However, when I hover over `dataA`, `#aDescription` does not appear. It works perfectly if I change the table data into paragraphs instead.

I have searched on Stack Overflow for an answer, and someone pointed out the use of `!important`, but even adding that made no difference.

What is going on, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Because there isn't element with id `aDescription` after the element with class `dataA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here isn't `:hover` but `+`: it only works when the second part is the element next to the first one (it's the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)).

You'll have to use javascript or to change your HTML.

**Solution 1: use `~` with a modified HTML:**

```css
#aDescription{
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.5s
}

.dataA:hover ~ #aDescription{
    opacity: 1 
}
```

```html
<div id=table>
  <span class=dataA>HELLO</span>
  <span class=dataB>LOL</span>
  
  <div id="aDescription">lol</div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2: use some JavaScript:**

```js
$('.dataA').hover(function(){
  $("#aDescription").toggleClass("shown");
})
```

```css
td{
    width: 50%
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center
}

#aDescription{
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 0.5s
}

#aDescription.shown {
    opacity: 1 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="dataA">HELLO</td>
        <td class="dataB">LOL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="aDescription">lol</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tables in HTML aren't usually the right solution to layout but it's hard to maintain your code when you have constraints like having elements being siblings. That's why the second solution is usually better.

Comment: @Hundotte As I wrote, there's none. You can't do that with just CSS.

Comment: Amazing answer! Very well explained and detailed. Thank you!